# href doesn't add url after adding class with .click() jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

CSS work properly. Buttons become active, when I click on it. BUT in the end of URL the data of href's doesn't add. It also works bad if I delete `e.preventDefault();`

Thank you in advance.

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';

  $("#header-navigation ul li").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#header-navigation ul li").removeClass("current-menu-item menu-item-has-children");
    $(this).addClass("current-menu-item menu-item-has-children");
  });

})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="header-navigation-wrap col-md-8">
  <div id="extended-bg">
    <nav id="header-navigation" class="header-navigation clearfix">
      <ul class="header-menu clearfix">
        <li class="current-menu-item menu-item-has-children">
          <a href="/">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/category">Category</a></li>
        <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="/feedback">Feedback</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with the url?

Comment: Clicking on a link will load a new page with a brand new javascript state, so the only thing that you do with the click handler is set the class on the clicked element for the 0.2 seconds that the old page is still visible.

Comment: @CarlEdwards for example, I click on the "category" button. URL looks like .../category. But the button isn't active ("home" is active), that's why I've used addClass() and removeClass(). After that "category" button becomes active for about ~0.5 seconds (URL looks like .../category). I've found I must use preventDefault() function. So, I've fixed the problem with ~0.5 seconds of well working, but URL looks like .../ always. Nothing changes, when I click on the buttons, views aren't loading.

Comment: I'd refer to James' comment above.

Comment: @James I can't catch what you are talking about :( templates are connected between each other, the main view Base.html includes the script. So, it must works everywhere. Isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally...

JS

```
(function () {
'use strict';

$('ul.header-menu li').click(function(){
    window.sessionStorage.activeMenuItem = this.id;
});

if (window.sessionStorage.activeMenuItem) {
    $("#"+sessionStorage.activeMenuItem).addClass('current-menu-item menu-item-has-children');
}
})();
```

HTML

```
<ul class="header-menu clearfix">
     <li id="liHome"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
     <li id="liCategory"><a href="/category">Category</a></li>
     <li id="liAbout"><a href="/about">About</a></li>
     <li id="liFeedback"><a href="/feedback">Feedback</a></li>
</ul>
```